# Is "síguenos" a real Spanish word?

Tags: vocabulario, significado, conjugación, palabras-raras, jerga-internet

The word "síguenos" does not appear in most of the major online English-Spanish dictionaries that I use such as Spanishdict.com. I only found one entry about it in a texting dictionary.

The word looks like a conjugation of the verb "seguir" but it doesn't appear to be so officially! Even Wiktionary.org does not have this word.

When googling it I only can find it used in the context of Facebook and Twitter in posts requesting that people "follow us". When I type "follow us" in English using google translate "síguenos" is the Spanish output.

I am very confused. Is "síguenos" a slang or a made up word? Where does the word "síguenos" come from? Finally, are there other Spanish words like this?

Comment: `Síguenos` exists and means "follow us". Not all the conjugations can be found in a dictionary; also, this specific is the union of `sigue` (imperative, 2nd form singular) and `nos` ("us").

Comment: @fedorqui  Why not use "sigamos" for follow us instead of "síguenos"? Also, why does "si" in "sigue" turn into "sí" with the accent mark?

Comment: @fedorqui That would be a good answer, instead of a comment.

Comment: @slyfin `Sigamos` is either _Presente de Subjuntivo_ or _Imperativo_ for `seguir` in 4th person (we). `Síguenos` is _Imperativo_ for `seguir` in 2nd person (you) with `nos` (to us) as _Complemento Indirecto_. By having three syllables and being the tonic accent on the first is a proparoxytone, and therefore always leads accent.

Comment: _Síganos_: formal (usted). _Síguenos_: informal (tú). Can you confuse _sigamos_ with _síganos_?

Comment: @Rodrigo Oh! Yes you are right! I did get confused there with sigamos. Thank you everyone for your help!

Comment: "Follow me" would be "sígueme" in Spanish, and this phrasing is much older than the Internet.  "síguenos" is the same phrase, only with a  plural object.

Answer (score 9):

*Síguenos* is a standard Spanish word. The verb *seguir* means “to follow.” Sigue is the affirmative *tú* command (second-person singular informal imperative) of seguir. *Nos* is a direct object pronoun that means “us.” With affirmative commands, pronouns are compounded with the imperative verb (that is, with the command). Therefore, *síguenos* means “follow us!” This appears frequently in social media contexts—for example, an advertisement for a business might say “*¡Síguenos en Facebook, Instagram y Twitter!*” (“Follow us on Facebook, Instagram, and Twitter!”)—which is probably why you could find it in a texting dictionary.

So why the accent with *síguenos*? Well, because *sigue* ends in a vowel, the accent lies on the second-to-last syllable, which is the same as the first syllable in this case. However, the rule is that if the word ends in a vowel, n, or s, the stress falls on the second-to-last syllable. Because *siguenos* (notice the lack of an accent) ends in an s, the stress would fall on the syllable *gue*. This, however, is incorrect, because whenever pronouns are compounded (as enclitics) with commands, participles, or infinitives, the stress must remain where it was originally without any attached pronoun. Therefore, the accent mark over the *i* in *síguenos* indicates that the stress should not be on the second-to-last syllable, but rather on the first syllable, where the stress was originally before the pronoun became attached to the command.

In short, the accent is added to keep the stress on the first syllable of *siguenos* after the pronoun is compounded with *sigue*, because otherwise the accent would fall on *gue*.

I recommend that you read about accent rules with pronouns and commands in Spanish [here](http://www.cliffsnotes.com/foreign-languages/spanish/spanish-ii/the-imperative/using-pronouns-with-commands).

Comment: I would argue that this is not a word, but a sentence. Am I wrong? Is "dígamelo" a word?

Comment: @LynHeadley: "Go!" is a sentence too. It is only a single word, but it is still a sentence. One word can be a sentence too. "Dígamelo" is in reality a word ("diga") with two enclitics attached, which aren't really words.

Comment: Sorry, didn't get your point about "digamelo." Are you saying that "digamelo" is not a word, but "siguenos" is a word?

Comment: @LynHeadley: Technically, neither of them are one word. Both "dígamelo" and "síguenos" are composed of verbs with enclitics. When I refer to "síguenos" as a word in my answer, I only do so in a very loose sense, simply for convenience.

Comment: @Aprendedor Thank you very much for your very thorough answers in English! My Spanish is at an extremely basic level so I would have an extremely difficult time understanding otherwise. I guess, since "síguenos" is not technically a word, that is why I couldn't find it any dictionaries including the RAE's online dictionary. I will definitely take your advice and read more about the accent rules with pronouns and commands. Muchas gracias!

Comment: @sylfin: No hay de qué. Yo también siempre estoy aprendiendo y tratando de mejorar mi español. Si mi respuesta te ha ayudado, yo le sugiero a usted que acepte mi respuesta por seleccionar la marca de visto bajo la flecha de downvote. No problem. I am also always learning and trying to improve my Spanish. If my answer helped you, I suggest that you accept my answer by clicking the check mark underneath the downvote arrow.

Answer (score 4):

These are called pronombres personales átonos *enclíticos* and you can find [an example on RAE's online dictionary](http://dle.rae.es/?id=F7C4wja).

*Sigue* is the 2nd person singular imperative for *follow*.

On the other hand, object pronouns such as *me, te, se, lo, la, le, nos, os, los, las, les* are called *átonos* in Spanish because the accent goes somewhere else, more precisely on the verb before, which they join in this case because it's in imperative mode.

This phenomenon's called *enclisis* and it also happens in other Romance languages, as Italian and Galician.

To sum up, *síguenos* it is an actual word and means "follow us", physically or online.

Answer (score 1):

Sure!  The verb is **seguir** + **nos** which is a [direct object](http://www.studyspanish.com/lessons/dopro1.htm) pronoun.

> *Yo te sigo.*
>
> I am following you.

Here is another one

> *El me sigue*
>
> He is following me.

In this example, [**seguir**](http://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/seguir) is an irregular verb: *sigo, sigues, sigue, seguimos, seguís, siguen*.  The imperative is *sigue*.

> *síguenos*
>
> Follow us!

This sounds like Facebook.  "Follow our page!"